# Windows Easy Transfer like tool for Windows 7 to 7 Migrations?

Tags: windows-7, windows, migration

I work in a corporate IT environment. Most of our users have been been migrated from Windows XP to 7. The techs in our company use the Easy Transfer tool to migrate people and it goes fairly smoothly.

Is there a tool that is similar that will let us pull user data from 7 to 7?

This is especially useful when users are upgrading from old laptop to a new one which is in many cases Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Windows Easy Transfer FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/transferring-files-and-settings-frequently-asked-questions) states:

> **Which versions of Windows will work with Windows Easy Transfer?**
>
> You can use Windows Easy Transfer to transfer files and settings from a computer running Windows XP, Windows Vista, or **Windows 7** to another computer running **Windows 7**.

It won't allow you to transfer data from a 64-bit version of Windows to a 32-bit version however.

Comment: Hey thanks for this...I didn't even try to run easy transfer on 7 thinking that it was only for XP to 7.